# What is "indrinking"

Tags: football, terminology

I popped into the middle of a conversation on the radio today. It was about the Dutch national football, about to play in the World Cup second round facing Mexico in Fortaleza. The conversation on the radio was about the heat (30+ C) and humidity (80%) at that location. These are tough conditions, but somehow they have a trick to minimize impact. It can freely be translated into "indrinking". What does "indrinking" mean in this context?

Comment: the ref is calling water breaks in some games - could it refer to that? Also sometimes "hurt" players who have rolled around clutching one of their legs (randomly chosen) are cured by getting a drink of water. Since everyone seems to fall to the ground hurt a lot, this technique could provide plenty of water.

Comment: @KateGregory No, it was especially refering to the preparation before the match.

Comment: *"It can freely be translated into "indrinking""* - So that wasn't the word you actually heard? Did you try to look up the original word, be it via google or at least a dictionary?

Comment: It was in Dutch, so there is no way to translate properly. The Dutch term "indrinken" is also used for teenagers drinking a lot of alcohol before a party.

Comment: If it was before the match, that would seem to rule out IVs.

Comment: @MichaelMyers IV? It was before the match, it might even be days before the match.

Comment: I heard in a post-match interview that they have been drinking lots of water the past few days. This might be what they mean, but I am curious if this works from a fysiological point of view.

Comment: Teenagers drinking alcohol before a party is called "pre drinking" in English

Comment: @KateGregory Ok, that makes sense. I couldn't find a proper translation.

Comment: Even if you drink liters and liters of water for days before they game, whatever you don't need then would be thrown away in the urine. To hold more water in the body, you would typically need to "fool" your body into holding onto more water, possibly by use of different salts. This is sort of the reverse process of water soluble "anti-hangover" tablets.

Comment: @posdef, I can imagine that it has to do with these kind of things, therefore I asked this question here. I am curious to learn from good resources :)

Comment: probably refers to the same technique used by endurance athletes prior to any event in a hot climate: make sure you are fully hydrated before the event by drinking sufficient water combined with minerals/salts such that your urine is coming out almost transparent. You can buy powders/tablets to add to water to make up the correct drink. These drinks do not include any energy component (carbs,sugars etc) but are purely meant to prevent dehydration. I would take the Dutch word ' indrinken' in the same way as 'inenten' ie an action taken to prevent a certain reaction (in this case dehydration).

Answer (score 1):

The term "pre-loading" may be closest to the idea expressed. This certainly applies if the same original Dutch word is used to describe drinking large amounts of alcohol before a party.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pregaming - "Pregaming (also pre-drinking or pre-loading) is the process of getting drunk prior to going out socializing, typically done by college students and young adults in the United States and Europe, ..."
http://i.stuff.co.nz/national/health/69157335/Alcohol-pre-loading-has-party-goers-arriving-at-bars-drunk - a discussion of the phenomenon and its health effects.

Answer (score -1):

I would guess that by "indrinken" he meant to drink enough so you wouldnt dehydrate too hard by the harsh weather